# Which is the correct way to change the texture of a polygon?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need a little help to achieve something with OpenGL ES 1.1

I have a simple square polygon (from nehe tutorials) with a texture.

The polygon haves a bitmap and the method loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) is called once, when the polygon is created, to load the texture.

I need to add the functionality to my app to change the texture of the square.

Which is the best way to change the texture of a polygon? can't find the right way on google...

thanks all

EDIT:

```
public class Square {
    //Buffer de vertices
    public FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    //Buffer de coordenadas de texturas
    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    //Puntero de texturas
    private int[] textures = new int[3];
    //El item a representar
    private Bitmap bitmap; //image with POT dimensions
    //size of the polygon:
    public float w;
    public float h;
    //size of the texture
    private float textureX;
    private float textureY; 
    //Definición de vertices    
    public float vertices[] = new float[12];
    private float vertices_transformed[] = new float[12];
    //Coordenadas (u, v) de las texturas    
    private float texture[];    
    // Image ratio
    float ratio;

    public int id;

    Context context;

    //Inicializamos los buffers
    public Square(Bitmap image, Context context) {      
        int bitmapW=image.getWidth();
        int bitmapH=image.getHeight();

            w=1.00f;
            h=(float)bitmapH/bitmapW;       


        float vertices2[] = { 
            -w, -h, 0.0f,   //Bottom Left
            w, -h, 0.0f,    //Bottom Right
            -w, h, 0.0f,    //Top Left
            w, h, 0.0f      //Top Right
        };
        vertices=vertices2;

        //calculamos la siguiente potencia de 2 del lado mas largo del bitmap, alto o ancho.
        int nextPOT; 
        if (bitmapW>bitmapH)
            nextPOT=getNextPOT(bitmapW);
        else
            nextPOT=getNextPOT(bitmapH);

        //creamos un nuevo bitmap cuadrado con dimensiones potencia de 2, y dentro de el metemos la imagen
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(nextPOT, nextPOT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //crea un bitmap transparente gracias al ARGB_8888
        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bitmap);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
        comboImage.save();      

        //calculamos las coordenadas de la textura dentro del bitmap que es potencia de 2
        textureX = (float)bitmapW / nextPOT;
        textureY = (float)bitmapH / nextPOT;

        //creamos el array de la textura, pasándole las coordenadas ya obtenidos
        float texture2[] ={
                0.0f,textureY,
                textureX, textureY,
                0.0f, 0.0f,
                textureX,0.0f
            };

        System.out.println("bw:"+bitmapW+"   nextPOT:"+nextPOT+"   texX:"+textureX);

        texture=texture2;   


        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);      

        //setPosition(0,0);

        ratio = (float)image.getWidth() / image.getHeight();

        image.recycle();
    } 

    //Funcion de dibujado
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        //Bind our only previously generated texture in this case
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        //Point to our vertex buffer
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
        //Enable vertex buffer
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        //Set The Color To Blue
        //gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
        //Draw the vertices as triangle strip
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
        //Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        //gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);      
    }

    //Carga de texturas
    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {       
        //Generamos un puntero de texturas
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);       
        //y se lo asignamos a nuestro array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        //Creamos filtros de texturas
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        //Diferentes parametros de textura posibles GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);     

        //Usamos Android GLUtils para espcificar una textura de 2 dimensiones para nuestro bitmap
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0); 

        //Checkeamos si el GL context es versión 1.1 y generamos los Mipmaps por Flag. Si no, llamamos a nuestra propia implementación
        if(gl instanceof GL11) {
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL11.GL_TRUE);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        } else {
            buildMipmap(gl, bitmap);
        }   
        //Limpiamos los bitmaps
        bitmap.recycle();       
    }

    //Nuestra implementación de MipMap. Escalamos el bitmap original hacia abajo por factor de 2 y lo asignamos como nuevo nivel de mipmap
    private void buildMipmap(GL10 gl, Bitmap bitmap) {
        int level = 0;
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        while(height >= 1 || width >= 1) {
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, bitmap, 0);
            if(height == 1 || width == 1) {
                break;
            }
            level++;
            height /= 2;
            width /= 2;
            Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = bitmap2;
        }
    }

    //returns the next POT
    public static int getNextPOT(int n){
        int i = 1;
        while(i < n)
            i *= 2;      
        return i;
    }

    public void setPosition( float x , float y ){
        vertexBuffer.put( 0 ,  vertices[0]+x );
        vertexBuffer.put( 3 ,  vertices[3]+x );
        vertexBuffer.put( 6 ,  vertices[6]+x );
        vertexBuffer.put( 9 ,  vertices[9]+x );

        vertexBuffer.put( 1 ,  vertices[1]+y );
        vertexBuffer.put( 4 ,  vertices[4]+y );
        vertexBuffer.put( 7 ,  vertices[7]+y );
        vertexBuffer.put( 10 ,  vertices[10]+y );       
    }

    public void move( float dx , float dy ){
        vertexBuffer.put( 0 ,  vertexBuffer.get(0)+dx );
        vertexBuffer.put( 3 ,  vertexBuffer.get(3)+dx );
        vertexBuffer.put( 6 ,  vertexBuffer.get(6)+dx );
        vertexBuffer.put( 9 ,  vertexBuffer.get(9)+dx );

        vertexBuffer.put( 1 ,  vertexBuffer.get(1)+dy );
        vertexBuffer.put( 4 ,  vertexBuffer.get(4)+dy );
        vertexBuffer.put( 7 ,  vertexBuffer.get(7)+dy );
        vertexBuffer.put( 10 ,  vertexBuffer.get(10)+dy );          
    }

    //CARGA DE TEXTURAS DIFERENTES PARA EL POLÍGONO
    static int[] mTextureNameWorkspace= new int[1];
    static int[] mCropWorkspace=new int[4];

    public int loadBitmap(Context context, GL10 gl, String imageName) {
        BitmapFactory.Options sBitmapOptions  = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        sBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        sBitmapOptions.inScaled=false;

        int textureName = -1;
        if (context != null && gl != null) {
            gl.glGenTextures(1, mTextureNameWorkspace, 0);
            textureName = mTextureNameWorkspace[0];
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            //gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);

            Bitmap bitmap = loadImage(imageName, context);

            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

            mCropWorkspace[0] = 0;
            mCropWorkspace[1] = bitmap.getHeight();
            mCropWorkspace[2] = bitmap.getWidth();
            mCropWorkspace[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();

            bitmap.recycle();

            ((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCropWorkspace, 0);
            textures[0]=textureName;
        }
        return textureName;
    }

    public static Bitmap loadImage( String imageName, Context context){
        if( imageName.charAt(0) == '/' ) {
            imageName = imageName.substring(1);
        }
        imageName = imageName + ".png";
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResourceAsStream(imageName, context));
        return image;
    }
    public static InputStream getResourceAsStream( String resourceName, Context context) {
        if( resourceName.charAt(0) == '/' ) {
            resourceName = resourceName.substring(1);
        }

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open( resourceName );
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return is;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [glTexSubImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glTexSubImage2D.html).

Comment: can you give me a little more explanation about this... ?

Comment: I'm no longer sure what you're asking. I thought you wanted to know how to update an existing texture, but maybe your question is more basic than that... SteveL's answer might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The things are a litle more complex than you think.
When you are using loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) opengl  loads ur texture and saves its id to a int  then in the render(of the polygon) function u use this id to specifi that this is the texture you want to draw.
You need to load your textures first ,save the id's on diferents int's and then render the polygon with the texture id you want;

First load you textures:

```
int txDog=loadBitmap(context,gl,R.drawable.dog);//This generetes an opengl texture id with the given image
int txCat=loadBitmap(context,gl,R.drawable.cat);
```

Next put an additional parameter to the polygon's render function called texid

```
public void Render(GL10 gl,int texid);
```

Then search in your render function for a line like this:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, thetexturenameid);
```

replace the thetexturenameid(or whatever is named) with texid

End for the end draw the polygon like this:

```
public void Render(gl,txDog);//if you want the dog texture
public void Render(gl,txCat);//if you want the cat texture




static int[] mTextureNameWorkspace= new int[1];
static int[] mCropWorkspace=new int[4];
public static int loadBitmap(Context context, GL10 gl, int resourceId) {
    BitmapFactory.Options sBitmapOptions  = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    sBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    sBitmapOptions.inScaled=false;


    int textureName = -1;
    if (context != null && gl != null) {
        gl.glGenTextures(1, mTextureNameWorkspace, 0);

        textureName = mTextureNameWorkspace[0];
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

      //  gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);
        gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL10.GL_MODULATE);


        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        Bitmap bitmap;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, sBitmapOptions);


        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        mCropWorkspace[0] = 0;
        mCropWorkspace[1] = bitmap.getHeight();
        mCropWorkspace[2] = bitmap.getWidth();
        mCropWorkspace[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();

        bitmap.recycle();

        ((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCropWorkspace, 0);




    }

    return textureName;
}
```

That's the simplest way i can explain it

Comment: i'm testing your code but something is going wrong, it is giving me white empty textures :S

Comment: I am using the same code in my game and all works fine.Is your textures size  power of two? Are you binding the correct texture before you draw?

Comment: Hi, i edited my post with my code, with your code merged, check, i'm telling in your function that textures[0]=textureName. This must changue the texture of the polygon, because textures[0] is used on the draw method.

I'm changing the texture on another class, a GLSurfaceView class, on the onDrawFrame method, with this line: square.loadBitmap(context, gl, "7"); (7 is the name of the bitmap)

Comment: please, tell me what i'm doing wrong, why the texture is showing white. There is no problem with the image, because that image is used in another polygon and it works fine.

Comment: On draw() method i dont see gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); do you enable the texture outside of the draw method? if not  put  gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D) before gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);